# Is it legal to plant trees in national forests?

Tags: united-states

There's a national forest near me that was burned in a wildfire. Would it be legal to plant trees there without getting some kind of license or permit?

Comment: From an ecologic standpoint, you should ask the wardens what type of tree is native there first, and from an organisational standpoint, you should work with them to get your trees to the best spots, but that's all not the legal problem

Comment: @Trish I know what types of trees are native, but good point about asking where to plant them .

Comment: just talking to the wardens, proposing your project, and then they might even help you carry them to the spots that are best or at least give you a special permit to leave ways and trails if needed. Collaborating with them also reduces double spending, in case they wanted to plant in the same area.

Comment: It's also entirely possible that they *don't* want the trees burnt up in the bushfire replaced, in order to create a firebreak against future bushfires.